# Images are not getting load in the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to load the sliding images in a web app and for that I'm using Bootstrap carousel. Fetched the images from the backend. The images are stored in the images state. Below is the JSON format of the data getting fetched.

```
images:[
{
SNO:'1',
NAME:'image.jpg',
PIC_NAME:'image'
}
]
```

When the images are uploaded, they are stored in a special folder in Nodejs, and from there, I'm extracting the images using an endpoint. Below is the Nodejs Code for that

```
images.get('/Images/getImages/:slug', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        root: path.join(__dirname, '/images')
    }
    res.sendFile(req.params.slug, options);
})
```

And below is the ReactJs code for fetching and showing the image in the web app:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import './landingPage.css'
import Instance from "../Axios/Instance";
const Carousal = () => {
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchImages();
    }, [])
    async function fetchImages() {
        const result = await Instance.get('/carousalimages/getImages');
        setImages(result.data);
    }
    console.log(images);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    {
                        images.map((pic) => {
                            return (
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <img src={`http://localhost:1200/Images/getImages/${pic.NAME}`} class="d-block w-100" alt={`${pic.PIC_NAME}`} />
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>

        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default Carousal;
```

But don't know why the images are not loading in the app. Please help and explain.
Also, I'm using the endpoint to fetch the images in img src like the below code

```
<img src={`http://localhost:1200/Images/getImages/${pic.NAME}`} class="d-block w-100" alt={`${pic.PIC_NAME}`} />
```

If there is a better way, please suggest.

Comment: Are images served correctly by your local server? For example, if you enter `http://localhost:1200/Images/getImages/image.jpg` in the url bar, do you see the actual image displayed?

Comment: @oozywaters. Yes they are correctly served.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the network error between the client and the server. As I assume the server runs from the different port, it should allow CORS config from the port where your react app is running (presumably 3000). You will easily figure out by checking out the dev tool especially the console tab.

Why don't you just store images in your react app static folder? Are images created dynamically everytime?

Comment: Hi @ junKim, yes the images are created dynamically.....Storing in a static manner means, everytime fetching it from database and storing in a react folder....that's what you mean, right ?

Comment: As long as image names are not changed every time, you can store images only one time and use them for good.

Answer (score -1):

you may import images like this

```
<img src={require(`./Images/getImages/${pic.NAME}`).default} class="d-block w-100" alt={`${pic.PIC_NAME}`} />
```

or

```
<img src={require(`./Images/getImages/${pic.NAME}`)} class="d-block w-100" alt={`${pic.PIC_NAME}`} />
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammad Mujtaba, I tried but the images are still not loading in the app.

Comment: @piyushshende are you available for quick zoom call ?

Comment: Can you please describe the solution here

Comment: I want to check the issue

Comment: If possible, please describe it here, will not be able to connect

Comment: you might be giving incorrect path of the images